# SQL join on different select count result-tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, count

I need some help on sql-joins.
I have 3 select statements, which give me an output like this:

```
select-statement A:
location amount_A
7234     17
7456     2

select-statement B:
location number_x
7234     4455
7456     555

select-statement C:
location errors
7234     1
7456     44537
```

I want to have the result in one table like this:

```
location Amount_A  number_x  errors
7234     17        4455      1
7456     2         555       44537
```

what is the best and/or easiest way to achieve this? Each select-statement uses other tables.?!

these are the statements:

```
A: select substring(column_a for 4) location, count(*) Amount_A from table_a where column_a like '7%' group by location  ;
B: select substring(e.column_xy for 4), count(*) number_x from table_b b, table_e e , table_c c where b.stationextension_id = e.id and b.id = c.id and ( c.column_h in ( 'value_a', 'value_b' ) ) group by substring(e.column_xy for 4)  ;
C: select substring(name from 1 for 4), count(*) from errors group by substring(name from 1 for 4) ;
```

Comment: thanks for editing to make it much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  a.location, a.amount_A,
  b.number_x,
  c.errors
from (
  select_satement_A
) as a
join (
  select_satement_B
) as b on a.location = b.location
join (
  select_satement_C
) as c on a.location = c.location
```

If all data from `select_satement_A` needs to be `retrieved` use `left join`.
All data from `select_satement_A` will be retrieved with corresponding data from`select_satement_B` and `select_satement_C`. If no match for the `join` condition found `null` will be substituted.

```
   select 
      a.location, a.amount_A,
      b.number_x,
      c.errors
    from (
      select_satement_A
    ) as a
    left join (
      select_satement_B
    ) as b on a.location = b.location
    left join (
      select_satement_C
    ) as c on a.location = c.location
```

For all data to be retrieved use `full join`.

Comment: works, but I get only 1 line in my result table - the values of this line are correct.

Comment: If you want all the `data` for all rows in `sele_state_A` then use `left join`. Update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Inner Join` to connect all the three queries.

Also use Inner Join syntax to join two tables which is more readable then old style comma separated join.

`Substring` function has some different arguments hope those are example in original query you need pass proper values to substring function

```
select a.location,Amount_A ,number_x,errors from
(
SELECT substring(column_a for 4) location, count(*) Amount_A FROM table_a WHERE column_a LIKE '7%' GROUP BY location  
) A 
inner join
(
SELECT substring(e.column_xy for 4) location , count(*) number_x FROM table_b b inner join table_e e on  b.stationextension_id = e.id and b.stationextension_id = e.id 
inner join  table_c c on  b.id = c.id 
where c.column_h IN ( 'value_a', 'value_b' ) ) GROUP BY substring(e.column_xy FOR 4)  ;
) B on a.location = b.location 
inner join 
(
SELECT substring(name from 1 FOR 4) location, count(*) errors FROM errors GROUP BY substring(name FROM 1 FOR 4) ;
)
C on c.location = b.location
```

Comment: The `SUBSTRING` function OP used looks like it came from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can join all three queries into one

```
SELECT s1.location,
       s1.Amount_A,
       s2.number_x,
       s3.errors
  FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING (column_a FOR 4) AS location,
    COUNT(*) AS Amount_A
  FROM table_a
    WHERE column_a LIKE '7%'
  GROUP BY location) s1
  JOIN ( SELECT SUBSTRING(e.column_xy FOR 4) AS location,
    COUNT(*) AS number_x
  FROM table_b b
    JOIN table_e e ON b.stationextension_id = e.id
    JOIN table_c c ON b.id = c.id
  WHERE c.column_h IN ( 'value_a', 'value_b' )
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(e.column_xy FOR 4)) s2
    ON s1.location = s2.location
  JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 FOR 4) AS location,
  COUNT(*) AS errors
  FROM errors
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 FOR 4)) s3 ON s1.location = s3.location
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always combine into one statement with some left outer joins. Locations may not have any errors i suppose.

Without a better understanding of the base data it's a bit tricky to get the joins in the correct order but i hope this points you in the right direction.

```
select  substring(e.column_xy for 4) location, 
        count(a.column_xy)           Amount_A, 
        count(e.ie)                  number_x, 
        count(e2.name)               errors
  from  table_b b
  inner join  table_e  e on b.stationextension_id        = e.id
  inner join  table_c  c on b.id                         = c.id
  left  join  table_a  a on substring(e.column_xy for 4) = substring(a.column_a from 1 for 4)
                        and a.column_a                like '7%'
  left  join  errors  e2 on substring(e.column_xy for 4) = substring(e2.name    from 1 for 4)
  where c.column_h in ( 'value_a', 'value_b' ) 
  group by substring(e.column_xy for 4);
```